# How to use SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty to get device's address?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

```
StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder();
address.Capacity = (int)DIGCF.MAX_DEV_LEN;
bool res2 = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                hDevInfo,
                ref DeviceInfoData,
                (UInt32)DIGCF.SPDRP_ADDRESS,
                0,
                address,
                (UInt32)DIGCF.MAX_DEV_LEN,
                IntPtr.Zero);

Console.WriteLine("res:"+res2);
if(res2) {
    Console.WriteLine(address);
}
```

My code is above, the return is true,but the address is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code so we can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The structures used by SetupDi are quite complicated and a real pain to translate into C#.  I suggest you try to make a simple example work in C++ first, where you can simply `#include <Setupapi.h>` and go.

Comment: And of course, first look at the properties using Device Manager to make sure that the Address property actually applies to the device you're inspecting.

Comment: you could try to use the sample in [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi/SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.html), if the sample works, then it could be caused by incorrect P/Invoke signature declaration or incorrect marshaling of the parameters.

Comment: @kennyzx: Looks like the sample code there is not even valid.